# Yelp Dataset Archives?

Tags: data-mining, dataset, bigdata

The Yelp Dataset Challenge (https://www.yelp.com/dataset_challenge) releases data for a handful of cities each year. I'd like to analyze some cities from past years. Is this data archived anywhere?

Comment: This Question can be migrated to Open Data SE.

Answer (score 1):

It is my understanding that the dataset gets updated / extended every year. It started with Phoenix, then they added Las Vegas, Madison, Waterloo and Edinburgh, and so on, for a total of 11 cities by 2017.

Basically, this year's dataset should also include all cities from previous years.

Comment: Interesting. Do you know of any documentation that says this?

Comment: I don't know about any official documentation but you can probably trace it back on their engineering blog, e.g. [here](https://engineeringblog.yelp.com/amp/2014/02/yelp-dataset-challenge-round-2-winner-and-new-data.html) [here](https://engineeringblog.yelp.com/2014/08/the-yelp-dataset-challenge-goes-international-new-data-new-cities-open-to-students-worldwide.html) and [here](https://engineeringblog.yelp.com/2015/02/yelp-dataset-challenge-is-doubling-up.html)